# Cron every 3 Hour not working, idea?

Tags: cron, centos7

I have a multiple crontab every minute, and 1 hour but now i need a cron every 3 hour

This cron working fine:

```
@reboot root /etc/init.d/httpd start
@reboot root /etc/init.d/mysqld start
@reboot root /etc/init.d/memcached start
@reboot root /etc/init.d/redis-server start
0 1 * * * root /home/./pulizie.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
0 4 * * * root /home/./backup.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
0 3 15 * * root /sbin/shutdown -r now
```

Now i have add this:

```
0 */3 * * * root /home/./database.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

But every 3 hour nothing start and log say:

```
Mar 26 00:01:01 mysvr anacron[16683]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Mar 26 01:00:01 mysvr CROND[16727]: (root) CMD (/home/./pulizie.sh >/dev/null 2>&1)
Mar 26 01:01:01 mysvr CROND[17344]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
Mar 26 04:00:01 mysvr CROND[19317]: (root) CMD (/home/./backup.sh >/dev/null 2>&1)
Mar 26 04:01:01 mysvr CROND[19571]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
Mar 27 00:01:02 mysvr anacron[24617]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
```

Do you have any idea?? I think cron is written in correct way

Comment: Restart the crond service? sudo systemctl restart crond.service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited the /etc/crontab with WinSCP but if use putty al work =)